# Wireless charging IC

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, wireless

I am building this wireless IC circuit and I don't understand the term HOST, TRI-STATE an BI-STATE. What do they mean?
[image: Schematic datasheet]

Comment: Did you read the datasheet and searched for HOST, TRI-STATE and BI-STATE?

Comment: Yes, i didn't found anything:/

Comment: "HOST" is the thing which is controlling or monitoring this charger circuit. "Tri-State" and 
"Bi-State" tell you a little about the characteristics of those signals, for example that the "TS/CTRL" signal has 3 states and that "EN2" has 2 states". "Tri" = 3, "Bi" = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BI-State is simply a digital logic output with two states high and low.

Tri-State is a digital logic output with three states high, low and high-Z. High-Z is a passive output with high internal resistance.

Several Tri-State outputs may be connect together if only one of them is in the state high or low and all other outputs is in the state high-Z.

HOST is a controlling microprocessor with two outputs connected to the charging IC.

Of course you should read the complete technical documentation on the web page:

https://www.ti.com/product/BQ51050B#tech-docs

the technical articles, the application notes, the user guide and *more literature*

Comment: okay, thank you Uwe!